# Verified user with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to create a login where the user only has to put his/her mail address and verify it via email. Using firebase I have this code so far:

- When the user clicks the button to login after putting the mail in the field. I try to create a new account (password is random as I don't need it). If it doesn't exists I send a verification mail. If the account exists I check with **checkIfVerifiedUser** if the user verified the account by clicking the mail or not.

  ```
  firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, Math.random() + "").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
          FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
          user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener((Activity) context, new OnCompleteListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                          if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                              Toast.makeText(context, "we sent a mail, please verify", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          } else {
                              Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          }
                      }
                  }); 
          checkIfVerifiedUser(email);
      } else {
          progressDialog.dismiss();
          try {
              throw task.getException();
          } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
        // In case the account already exists
              checkIfVerifiedUser(email);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(context, R.string.error_auth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }
  }    });
  ```

Here is the method I call:

```
private void checkIfVerifiedUser(String email){
        final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        if(user != null){
            user.reload();
            // If the user is created, we check if the account is verified
            if(user.isEmailVerified()) {
                intent.putExtra(IntentEnum.ALREADYREGISTERED.getCode(), true);
            }else{
                intent.putExtra(IntentEnum.ALREADYREGISTERED.getCode(), false);
            }
        }else{
            intent.putExtra(IntentEnum.ALREADYREGISTERED.getCode(), false);
        }
        ---rest of code---
    }
```

The problem is that I either get firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null or user.isEmailVerified() always false (even if I click the link in the email I get sent).

Could anyone help me with this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to call `checkIfVerifiedUser()` method inside `onComplete()` method and inside the if statement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, you are not. It is placed outside the scope. You need to move it inside the if statement.

Comment: No, firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() keeps being null.

Comment: It seems that did not initilized the `firebaseAuth` and that's why is null. You need to use this: `FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();` Does it work?

Comment: It's initializated in the onCreate

Comment: Did you checked for nullity?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that in order to access the current user I need to log in first (using user/pass). In my case I create the account with a random password because I don't need the password in my app so when I try to access it again once validated via email, I can't do it because it requires the pass to do so. I wonder if there is another way to log in only with mail+validated account.

Comment: No, there is not. You can find another approach, [Authenticate with Firebase Anonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) in which you don't need the email and nor the password. What do you think? Can this solve your problem?

Comment: Afraid not! The app can only be access by people who verified their address :/

Comment: In this case the only choice is to implement an autentication process containg his own mechanism.